# Save to %temp% folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to save embedded Word document from Excel to Windows %temp% folder. My current solution is not working. Where is the mistake?

```
Dim tempFolderPath As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileTitle As String

    tempFolderPath = Environ("Temp")
    fileTitle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK7").Value & "_" & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK8").Value & "_" & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AU2").Value
    objWord.SaveAs2 filePath = tempFolderPath & "\" & fileTitle & ".docx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveAs2` method doesn't have a property called `filePath`. I think you're looking for `FileName`.

Try this:

```
objWord.SaveAs2 FileName:= tempFolderPath & "\" & fileTitle & ".docx"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its good practice to put  Option Explicit at the top of every module.  Its also good practice to put the cursor on keywords such as SaveAs2 and press F1 before asking questions here.

Comment: @Freeflow Why would you direct this comment towards the person who answered the question? The OP, who has the problem, won't see this...

Comment: Because I'm stupid and keep forgetting that there isn't a consolidated list of comments.